I can't find bake to F curve
I was trying to find bake to F curve in graph editor so that I can make displace modifier react to my wav file. I tried finding it inside Key and channel but it's still not there. My blender is 4.0.2 and Im on Mac. Please Please help 

you have to insert one keyframe before you can do that.

It has changed in a recent update of Blender. It has been renamed : Sound to Samples :

After doing it, you may want to convert your samples to keyframes with Samples to Keys, shown as half-dotted arrow.
